# Trouble using parcels to send Object of unknown datatype

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I asked a question the other day regarding sending an object to an activity using an intent as a parcel but I am unsure how to do it in my situation. I have a variable of type object `Object x;` which is set with something like this: `x = edit.getText().toString();` and in this instance x becomes a String object but I also have it able to set x as both an Integer and an SQLDate type. Looking at examples of how to send an object as a parcel it seems to me you have to know what the datatype is before hand even for custom datatypes. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated as i'm completely stuck on this.

Flow is:

`Object x;` - is created.

`x = String object||Integer object||sqldate object` - x is assigned a value

`i.putExtra("object", x);` - x is sent through to the next activity after being parcelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement on the data you pass inn is that it is serializable in some way, and yes, both `String` and `Integer` are. Also, if you're using [`java.sql.Date`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Date.html), this type inherits [`util.Date`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) which in turn inherits [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html). The slight "problem" is that `Intent.putExtra` does not have an overload that takes `Object` as parameter type. Thus, you would have to "know" which data type you want to put:

```
if (goingToUseStringObject...)
{
    // use the CharSequence overload
    i.putExtra("object", stringObject);
}
else if (goingToUseIntegerObject...)
{
    // use the int overload
    i.putExtra("object", integerObject);
}
else if (goingToUseDateObject...)
{
    // use the Serializable overload
    i.putExtra("object", dateObject);
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere there is quite a big overhead, do you think it's worth it to send the date object through as a string and then re-convert it in the next activity? I only need to store the dd/MM/yyyy so i'm not fussed about losing the time part.

Comment: @SamRowley - I don't know if it is that big. But sure, serializing only what you need will certainly be the fastest option. But with all performance related issues, don't pre-optimize. If testing shows there's a huge difference, then go for it. If not, do the simplest thing.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having an `Object` reference that can be one of 3 other different data-types, I'd suggest making a wrapper class that implements `Parcelable` that stores the data for you. If you're passing this data around a lot, it will make your life much simpler.